# CS50 PSET4 Filter Blur Black Photo

Tags: c, image, image-processing, bitmap, cs50

When I run the program it outputs a black picture for some reason. The goal is to use box blur effect and get all the RGB values for all pixels within 1 row and column and find the average

[image: Grid of pixels]

For example, if I want to find the new value of 6, each of the color values for pixel 6 would be obtained by averaging the original color values of pixels 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, and 11 (note that pixel 6 itself is included in the average). For a pixel along the edge or corner, like pixel 15, we would still look for all pixels within 1 row and column: in this case, pixels 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, and 16.

What am I doing wrong here?

```c
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Stores pixels temporarily for reference to get blur
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

       for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int xarr[3] = {j - 1, j, j + 1};
            int yarr[3] = {i - 1, i, i + 1};
            // Goes through array
            int y = 0, x = 0;
            int sumcount = 0;
            RGBTRIPLE sum;
            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
            {
                if (x == 3)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y++;
                }
                if (!(xarr[x] < 0 || xarr[x] > width || yarr[y] < 0 || yarr[y] > height))
                {
                    sum.rgbtRed += temp[yarr[y]][xarr[x]].rgbtRed;
                    sum.rgbtGreen += temp[yarr[y]][xarr[x]].rgbtGreen;
                    sum.rgbtBlue += temp[yarr[y]][xarr[x]].rgbtBlue;
                    // Counts added pixels
                    sumcount++;
                }
                x++;
            }
            // Finds average and assigns
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (float) sum.rgbtRed / sumcount);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round( (float) sum.rgbtGreen / sumcount);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round( (float) sum.rgbtBlue / sumcount);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Firstly you didn't initialise `RGBTRIPLE sum;` and it's no good anyway, because each component cannot store the *sum* of the neighbours: only `255`. Use separate variables like `int rsum = 0; int gsum = 0; int bsum = 0;`

Comment: And, don't step out of bounds with for instance, `xarr[x] > width`... Use `>=` for avoiding too much width or too much height.